# runserver.py giving Module Error while setup MDM server code

Tags: python, ios, mdm

I am trying to setup this git code on Ubuntu server
https://github.com/jessepeterson/commandment

I have managed to install the required packages
https://github.com/jessepeterson/commandment/blob/master/requirements.txt

- M2Crypto<0.25
- pyOpenSSL
- Flask
- SQLAlchemy
- apns
- oauthlib
- passlib
- biplist

  Now when I run the runserver.py file 
  it is giving me some Module Error

[image: Please see the attach image]

Please let me know how can I setup this code

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if apns module is installed by `pip list`

If it is not installed, Please install apns module by `pip install apns`

If already part installed, check if it is part of your virtualenv PYTHONPATH, if you are using virtualenv

Comment: Thank you very much
can you please see this and help me out
from  [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533555/apply-polices-restrict-app-on-ios-using-mdm-on-already-install-profile)